# Couldn't find package after npm pack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to create an npm library with using `lerna` as my handler for workspaces, my project structure looks like below:

```
- packages
-- commons
--- package.json
--- .npmignore
-- core
--- package.json
--- .npmignore
- package.json
```

dependencies for `commons/package.json`:

```
"core": "0.0.1"
```

dependencies for `core/package.json`:

```
"commons": "0.0.1"
```

After running `build` and then `npm pack` in my `core` package, npm create for me an `core-0.0.1.tgz` file. Then this file I copy to root directory in my test project where I add to dependencies in package.json like below:

```
"core":"file:core-0.0.1.tgz"
```

and run `yarn` to install this package. And now I have a problem, cause my console throw me this:

```
error Couldn't find package "core/commons@0.0.1" required by "core@file:core-0.0.1.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
```

and I don't know why, because everything in my `lerna` workspace is looking good

can someone show me what am I doing wrong?

thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't add `yarn add core/commons` cause i working on local packages

Comment: I am assuming you are requiring the file incorrectly in one of the package.json files(likely core but that is a guess).  What is the content of those files?  It seems like it is finding your `file:core-0.0.1.tgz` file but looking for the others on NPM.

Comment: I thnik that the problem is in that before build `core` package I need already have published `commons` in npm registry because on `yarn`, my `core` package install all dependencies what they need but only from npm, not from local cause i have a different version nomenclature like `file:core-0.0.1.tgz` instead of `0.0.1`

Comment: And right now I have two ways, one is to rebuild my project structure, resign from lerna and use monolith structure or publish every packages to npm and update on every changes...

Comment: You know you can require a local file in NPM though right?